# C# How to tell the difference of HTML tags?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I am making a program that takes soccer stats from a website and stores it. The problem is there is no difference between how the site stores the different states in the HTML code.

code snippet from the website:

```
    // First Team
    <td style="background-color:#79a6ca;"><!-- --></td>
            <td class="t_c" style="border-right:1px #dddddd solid; background-color:#ebf2f7;">2</td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ebf2f7;"><img src="/assets/images/logo/participants/16x16/8113.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="FC Midtjylland" title="FC Midtjylland" /> <a href="/fodboldklubber/fc-midtjylland/" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333;">FC Midtjylland</a></td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">14</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">8</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">3</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">3</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="border-left:1px #dddddd solid; border-right:1px #dddddd solid; background-color:#ebf2f7;">19 - 10</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#ebf2f7;">27</td>
            </tr>
// Second team
                    <tr data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Europa League kvalifikation">
            <td style="background-color:#79a6ca;"><!-- --></td>
            <td class="t_c" style="border-right:1px #dddddd solid; background-color:#ebf2f7;">3</td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ebf2f7;"><img src="/assets/images/logo/participants/16x16/8595.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Brøndby IF" title="Brøndby IF" /> <a href="/fodboldklubber/broendby-if/" style="font-weight:bold; color:#333;">Brøndby IF</a></td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">14</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">7</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">3</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="background-color:#ebf2f7;">4</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="border-left:1px #dddddd solid; border-right:1px #dddddd solid; background-color:#ebf2f7;">24 - 17</td>
            <td class="t_c" style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#ebf2f7;">24</td>
            </tr>
```

I am using WebClient to download the page and MatchCollection to search for the desired pattern.
The plan is to write the value to a string array.

I have tried JStromwick example and it kind of works, but it doesn't stop after the team. It also takes the next team with. How do I work around this. Can I put in a counter?

My code so far:

```
string[] superLigaHold = new string[] { "FC Midtjylland", "Brøndby IF" };
for (int i = 0; i < superLigaHold.Length; i++)
            {
                string teamPattern = "<img src.*? width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\" alt=\"" + superLigaHold[i] + "\" title=\"" + superLigaHold[i] + "\" />";
                MatchCollection team = Regex.Matches(webPage, teamPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);               
                if (team.Count > 0)
                {
                        var gameStats = Regex.Matches(webPage, "<td.+?>(\d+).*");              
                        string gamesTotal = gameStats[0].Groups[1].Value;
                        string gamesWon = gameStats[1].Groups[1].Value;
                        string gamesDraw = gameStats[2].Groups[1].Value;
                        string gamesLost = gameStats[3].Groups[1].Value;                                                }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer but i can't figure this is possible if you only get that html and nothing more :/.. is this html always in this order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there isn't any other information from the HTML the only thing you can go off of is the column order. If you have the above HTML as a string you can use a regex with a capture group to find the values you are looking for. Something like:

```
var html = 
    @"<td class=""t_c"" style=""background-color:#f2faf2;"">14</td> // Total matches
    <td class=""t_c"" style=""background-color:#f2faf2;"">9</td> // Won matches
    <td class=""t_c"" style=""background-color:#f2faf2;"">3</td> // Draw matches
    <td class=""t_c"" style=""background-color:#f2faf2;"">2</td> // Lost matches";

var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"<td.+?>(\d+).*");

var totalMatches = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
var wonMatches = matches[1].Groups[1].Value;
var drawMatches = matches[2].Groups[1].Value;
var lostMatches = matches[3].Groups[1].Value;
```

You can get more information on regex's from 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

And I have found http://regexhero.net/tester/ to be a handy tool for testing (requires Silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS Selector engine like https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Then ( css wise), total matches would be:

```
var matches = dom.Select(".t_c");
string total_matches = matches[0].InnerText; //=first occurence of the class .t_c
string won_matches = matches[1].InnerText;
string draw_matches =matches[2].InnerText;
string lost_matches =matches[3].InnerText;
```

It will also help you parse other html elements easily without the difficulty of Regular Expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use [htmlagilitypack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode bodyContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");   
var all_td = bodyContent.SelectNodes("//td");

foreach (var node in all_td) 
{
    //Put your code here
}
```